# Creating a correct query with joins

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am very sorry if I post such a trivial question, but I am really stuck and Google couldn't help me, maybe because I am new with Ruby on Rails.

I have two tables:
**Person**
id : Integer
name : String

**Address**
id: Integer
person_id : Integer
name : String

I would like to retrieve a `Person` joined with an `Address`. This code snippet works, but only if there is actually an address available for this person:

```
@person = Person.where('person.id' => params[:id])
                 .joins(:address)
                 .select('person.id as id, address.id as aid, person.name as name, address.name as aname').first
```

My view:

```
<h2><%= @person.name %></h2>
<p><%= @person.aname %></p>
```

Maybe I a m doing something conceptional wrong. As I said as soon as a `Person` has a related `Address`, my view displays it, otherwise if there is no `Address` it prints an error.

Comment: What is the error that you got?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might consider using `.includes(:relation)` method to generate a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` query. Also, consider using `.find(:id)` method to look for a person with specific primary key. This will make your query simpler.

```
@person = Person.find(params[:id]).includes(:address)
```

Also, you may want to call address fields in your view like this:

```
<h2><%= @person.name %></h2>
<p><%= @person.address.try(:name) %></p>
```

---

**NOTE:** Calling name on address (`@person.address.name`) violates [Law of Demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) and you should consider adding a `address_name` method to your `Person` class. In rails, you can use `delegates :x, to: :y` syntax.

Comment: Ok it seems a bit better, thank you for your reply. But I have still some problems. When I do `<%= @person.address %>` I can see that there are some attributes with there values (under *raw_attributes*), but when i try to call it `<%= @person.address.name %>` an error appears: `undefined method name' for #<Address::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy`

Comment: Do you have `has_one` or `has_many` association? It looks like the later. You are getting a list of addresses instead of just one. Change `has_many: addresses` to `has_one :address`.

Comment: I got it! I had to loop `@person.address`, even if it's only getting one entry back. Is there a possibility to get rid of the loop, because I want to define the query, so it only gets my one address (I will add a boolean flag called active in the address, so that only one address is active)

Comment: Yeap, define your own `scope` or method that returns needed address.